# The increment ++ operator doesn't work for setting react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to do a simple counter with react, and I found that `++` doesn't work. I wonder why.

This worked

```
..

addCount() {
  this.setState({count:this.state.count+1})
}
..
```

But this will not work

```
..

addCount() {
  this.setState({count:this.state.count++})
}
..
```

You can try it here
https://jsfiddle.net/Lwvbe2o2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Why

Because `x++` expression first returns the value of `x` then it increments it, while `++x` first increments it, then returns that incremented value.

Just for experimentation purposes, you can verify this by using the *preincrement* like this

```
// Don't do this, it's just to explain why it works.
addCount () {
  this.setState({count: ++this.state.count})
}
```

Then it'll do what you want, however it's not idiotmatic, because it does mutate directly `this.state.count`.

### Idiomatic way

In ReactJS you don't want to mutate `this.state.count` directly, so your first example is more idiomatic:

```
addCount () {
  this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1})
}
```

### References

[MDN postfix/prefix increment operator ++](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_())

Comment: Note that I am answering to "I wonder why" in your question. Otherwise `this.setState({count:this.state.count + 1})` is more idiomatic.

Comment: ah make sense! tq

Answer (score 0):

When you do ´a = b++´, you first assign the value of b to a, then you increment b. It's called post incrementation. 
In your example it's the same : ´count´ will be equal to ´this.state.count´ (So the value will be the same) and then you increment ´this.state.count´, but it will be replace by ´count´ when setState finish because you change the state. setState is here to set your variable, don't mutate it in this method.

Your first proposition is the way to do what you want.

Hope this helps !